# crear variables de forma dinámica Javascript

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Estoy intentando hacer unas variables dinámicas para crear varios elementos y destruir otros, es decir, siguiendo el flujograma, cada que se invoque la función tendría yo una nueva variable dinámica:
    var rcc = 0;
    var lastGeoCoder;

```
function routesControl(b) {

  var geoControl + '_' + rcc = new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
  });
  var lastGeocoder = geoControl + '_' + rcc;
  if (b)
    map.addControl(geoControl + '_' + rcc, 'top-left');
  else
    map.removeControl(lastGeocoder);
  rcc++;
  console.log((rcc + 1)+' llamada: '+ geoControl + '_' + rcc);
}
```

> ```
> 1 llamada: geoControl_0
> 2 llamada: geoControl_1
> 3 llamada: geoControl_2
> ...
> ```

Espero haberme expresado correctamente, osea solo quiero que las variables se nombren dinámicamente, no se como hacerlo

Bienvenidas sugerencias

Comment: Me parece que estás encarando esto de una forma demasiado complicada, sin sentido. Te recomiendo leer sobre **[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function routesControl(b) {

  var geoControl + '_' + rcc = new MapboxDirections({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
  });
  var lastGeocoder = geoControl + '_' + rcc;
  if (b)
    map.addControl(geoControl + '_' + rcc, 'top-left');
  else
    map.removeControl(lastGeocoder);
  rcc++;
  console.log((rcc + 1)+' llamada: '+ geoControl + '_' + rcc);
}
```

Con tu código deberia probar lo que hace cada `class` pero creo que con

```
 var rcc = 0;
 console.log(eval("var geoControl_" 
 + rcc 
 + "= new MapboxDirections({accessToken:mapboxgl.accessToken});"));
 alert(geoControl_0);
```

Lo tendrías. Es algo así como el doble "$$" en PHP.